# Why can I redefine variable name from parameter?

Tags: swift

I don't understand how this compiles and works:

```
struct Person {
    var age: Int

    init(age: Int) {
        self.age = age

        // Another age?!
        let age = age + 1
    }
}
```

How can the compiler see the difference between those triple variables with all the same names inside the same block? After I defined `age` for the last time, can I still access `age` from the parameter list?

Does the lifetime of a parameter variable ends when another variable has been created with the same name? I don't think so according to this small test:

```
struct Person {
    init(child: Child) {
        print("copied another child reference")
        var child: Child? = child

        print("Emptying reference")
        child = nil
        print("Bye bye hasn't been called yet, but where is the last reference?")
    }
}

class Child {
    deinit {
        print("bye bye")
    }
}

// Somewhere call Person(child: Child())
```

"bye bye" is called as last print statement. It means it somehow keeps a reference although I do not see how I can still access the parameter child object.

Comment: The new `age` shadows the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `init(child:)`, the parameter named `child` is scoped for the whole function body. Its lifetime ends when the function ends. This is why the `print` in `deinit` isn't called until the end.

The local variable named `child` doesn't change the lifetime of the parameter named `child`. But the local variable does change the visibility of the parameter. After line:

```
var child: Child? = child
```

you can't access the parameter named `child` any more but its lifetime hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

- `var age: Int` is the (global) struct member
- `init(age: Int)` is the passed parameter which hides the struct member unless it's referenced with `self`
- `let age =` is a local variable which hides the init parameter **and** the struct member. The struct member is still available with `self` while the `init` parameter is invisible but alive.